# How to fix the Unity C# error CS0117: 'UnityWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'redirectLimit'?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to Unity, and recently I've begun working on my first mobile game using C#, and suddenly I get the CS0117 error and I don't know why since my code is pretty simple and the console won't specify in which line the error occurs. I received the error when I wrote the simple line:

```
transform.position = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
```

in my player script to set it's position to the same as the position of the camera. I don't think that this has anything to do with the script itself, but that it is a problem with my phone, but I don't know what the problem is.

In case you need it, here are the full scripts of the player and the camera.

player script:

```
public class playerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //movement
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            touchPosition.z = 0f;
            transform.position = touchPosition;
        }

        //borders
        if (transform.position.x >= 2.3f)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(2.3f ,transform.position.y, 0);
        }
        if (transform.position.x <= -2.3f)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(-2.3f ,transform.position.y, 0);   
        }
        if (transform.position.y >= 4.5f)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 4.5f, 0);
        } 
        if (transform.position.y <= -4.5f)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, -4.5f, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Camera script:

```
    public class cameraScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: That error does not relate to any of the code you have shown. Where are you using UnityWebRequest?

Comment: I haven't written that in my code, I don't even know what it is lol

Comment: Well it will tell you which file it stems from.   Find that file. Either the version of something you added isn’t compatible or out of date

Comment: I opened the file and I found a 130 line-long C# script, but there doesn't seem anything wrong with it, and there is only one version of the file avaiable and that's the one I have.

Comment: nvm, it's fixed. I updated Unity itself